# Getting current location but only once

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cllocationmanager

In my **ViewController** I need to update to current location on `viewDidLoad` just to download right data from server. Data should be downloaded only once just to fill the `tableView` but user has right to **pull-to-refresh** which will get the current location and call `reloadData`.

I don't want this data to be reloaded automatically when `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method is called what is the cleanest way to refill the `tableView`. another soultion is **KVO** on `currentLocation` but the results are the same - need to call reload everytime location is updated. It should be managed by user manually (just like in example above). I don't have any idea how to do this without raloading `tableView` every time locations are updated.

Any lead in this case would be a big help!

Comment: Share your code for better understanding..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `[locationmanager stopUpdatingLocation]` in `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` and on pulltorefresh `[locationmanager startUpdatingLocation]`.

To update a particular cell you can find the reference from the table view and try to get the reference of the control to update that

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is the right one for my purpose and it's totally sufficient but... Ifanyone ever would be interested in ready soultion which is clean, nice and supports **Cocoapods** you should try [`INTULocationManager`](https://github.com/intuit/LocationManager).

This little library gives you a pretty handy methods which will wait for your localization or give you back the best possible result. Everything packed in nice block syntax.